# Buck converter: what determines the inductor voltage?

Tags: power, buck

I am studying buck converters and have nearly grasped their ideal workings in the Continuous Conduction Mode however there is one last bit that I can't get a confident grasp with.

When the transistor switch is OFF, what makes the inductor voltage go negative? Is it that at that instant the diode is not in forward bias mode, it has therefore undergone a large negative
\$ di \over dt \$ according to

$$
V = L { di \over dt }
$$

and therefore a negative voltage is applied across it from say 5V to say -0.6V which is a typical diode forward voltage.

What restricts the maximum value of this voltage?

Comment: You pretty much have it. First the FET turns off. This starves the inductor, and causes the inductor voltage to go negative very rapidly. When it gets to -0.6 (or whatever) the diode conducts, so L*di/dt is now Vout-0.6 (or whatever). Basically, once the diode goes into forward conduction, the fast voltage change halts, because the inductor is satisfied by current again.

Comment: Including a schematic in  your question would help people answer consistent with your understanding of the circuit.

Comment: @mkeith Why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all down to Kirchhoff's voltage law. Let's look at a circuit:
[image: BUCK]
Consider the instant the switch is opened. Your input is disconnected, which means:
$$V_\mathrm{out} + V_\mathrm{inductor} + V_\mathrm{diode} = 0$$

This is where the negative voltage is coming from. The output voltage cannot change instantaneously because of the capacitor. This means that the inductor voltage needs to become negative in order to satisfy Kirchhoff's voltage law.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that there is certainly a negative voltage applied across the inductor. The diode is connected so as to be reverse biased on the normal flow of the circuit.

When the circuit has attained steady state with the switch closed, at that time the diode is still reverse biased and only passing some negligible current. At the time when the switch is opened, for a normal resistor, we know that the current will drop to zero almost immediately, but in the case of an inductor, it will try to restrict the decay of the current by applying a very high negative voltage which is dependent on both the inductor, time it takes for the switch to open and the core resistance of the inductor.

In fact, the reason why the inductor behaves that way is because it actually stores energy in its magnetic field. So when you stop the current from flowing, it returns all the energy it has stored. This will be seen as a voltage spike that may damage the switching component.

The purpose of the fly-back diode is that when the starts inducing a negative voltage, the diode will become forward biased and will have a forward voltage drop of 0.6v - 1v. Because of this, current will continue to be supplied to the inductor which will satisfy the inductor. Of course it is important that the diode should be able to handle the current flowing through the inductor.

Now because of power loss between the diode and the inductor core resistance, the inductor current will decay to zero after a while.

Comment: You are a bit mixed up. The inductor current will decay because the voltage applied to it is in the reverse direction of the current through it. Also, the diode is not just to prevent voltage spikes. It is an integral part of the power conversion system. Without either  a diode or synchronous switching device, the whole buck regulator concept would not work.

Answer (score 0):

The basic inductor property is that it doesn't change current instantly. That means, electrons keep flowing in same direction and with same current as before switching. And that changes the charge on switching node, so voltage drops. Drops until diode starts to conduct forward.